# How can I make this regex match correctly?

Tags: c#, regex

Given this regex:

```
^((https?|ftp):(\/{2}))?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)*?))(\.)([a-z]{2}
|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum){1})
```

Reformatted for readability:

```
@"^((https?|ftp):(\/{2}))?" + // http://, https://, ftp:// - Protocol Optional
@"(" + // Begin URL payload format section
@"((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" + // IPv4 Address support
@")|("+ // Delimit supported payload types
@"((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)*?))(\.)([a-z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum){1}" + // FQDNs
@")"; // End URL payload format section
```

**How can I make it fail (i.e. not match) on this "fail" test case?**

```
http://www.google
```

As I am specifying {1} on the TLD section, I would think it would fail without the extension. Am I wrong?

Edit: These are my PASS conditions:

- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&PID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&ID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com/?Req=Post&PID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&PostID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com/?Req=Post&ID=4"
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Post=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Entry=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?PID=4"
- "http://www.zi255.com/Post.aspx?Req=Post&ID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com/Post.aspx?Req=Post&PID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com/Post.aspx?Req=Post&Post=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com/Post.aspx?Req=Post&Title=Random%20Post%20Name"
- "http://www.zi255.com/?Req=Post&Title=Random%20Post%20Name",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Title=Random%20Post%20Name",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&PostID=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Post=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Entry=4",
- "http://www.zi255.com?PID=4"
- "http://www.zi255.com",
- "http://www.damnednice.com"

These are my FAIL conditions:

- "http://.com",
- "http://.com/",
- "http:/www.google.com",
- "http:/www.google.com/",
- "http://www.google",
- "http://www.googlecom",
- "http://www.google.c",
- ".com",
- "https://www..."

Comment: That regex is pathological. Doesn't C# have a URL validation mechanism? I know PHP does. It is also an incomplete check for valid URLs (eg limited TLDs, http://1000000000 is an alternative for dot notation, usage of usernames (optionally with passwords), etc). Is this convoluted regex really necessary?

Comment: Your regex also fails to match on http://www.un.int. :)

Comment: @Cletus: Googling shows that most URL validation in C# is done via regex.

Comment: @Greg: According to http://www.regextester.com/ it does match un.int, though that confuses me when I look at the {2} in the TLD section... Odd...

Comment: What about non US urls *.co.uk *.com.au etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll throw out an alternative suggestion.  You may want to use a combination of the parsing of the built-in `System.Uri` class and a couple targeted regexes (or simple string checks when appropriate).

Example:

```
string uriString = "...";

Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    // Uri is totally invalid!
}
else
{
    // validate the scheme
    if (!uri.Scheme.Equals("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // not http!
    }

    // validate the authority ('www.blah.com:1234' portion)
    if (uri.Authority // ...)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, one catch-all reqex is not the best solution, however tempting. While debugging this regex is feasible (see Greg Hewgills answer), consider doing a couple of tests for different categories of problems, e.g. one test for numerical addresses and one test for named addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to force your regex to match up until the end of the string. Add a `$` at the very end of it. Otherwise, your regex is probably just matching `http://`, or something else shorter than your whole string.

Comment: When I do that, it fails on (Actually correct, but edited so MarkDown shows it right): http www.zi255.com?Req=Post&Post=4

Comment: That wasn't part of your question! I think you need to specify more carefully exactly what you *do* want your regular expression to match, and also just as importantly, what you *don't* want it to match.

Comment: Sorry, added my test conditions for clarity.

Comment: +1 as this did solve the original problem as (poorly) stated.

Answer (score 1):

The "validate a url" problem has been solved* numerous times. I suggest you use the `System.Uri` class, it validates more cases than you can shake a stick at.

The code `Uri uri = new Uri("http://whatever");` throws a `UriFormatException` if it fails validation. That is probably what you'd want.

*) Or kind of solved. It's actually pretty tricky to define what is a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about definitions, a "valid url" should provide you with a IP address when you do a DNS Lookup. The IP should be connected to and when a request is send out, you get a reply in the form of a HTML information that you can use.

So what we are looking for is a "valid URL Format" and that is where the `system.uri` comes in very handy. BUT, if the URL is hidden in a large piece of tekst, you would first like to find something that validates as a valid URL-Format.

The thing that distinquishes a URL from any given readable tekst is the dot not followed by whitespace. "123.com" could validate as a real URL.

Using the regex

```
[a-z_\.\-0-9]+\.[a-z]+[^ ]*
```

to find any possible valid url in a text and then do a system.uri check to see if its a valid URL format and then do a lookup. Only when the lookup gives you a result then you know the URL is valid.