# This regex matches and shouldn't. Why is it?

Tags: regex

This regex:

> ^((https?|ftp)\:(\/\/)|(file\:\/{2,3}))?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
> (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)?)+?)(\.)([a-z]{2}
> |com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum))([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\&\%\/]*)?$

Formatted for readability:

```
^( # Begin regex / begin address clause
  (https?|ftp)\:(\/\/)|(file\:\/{2,3}))? # protocol
  ( # container for two address formats, more to come later
   ((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
   (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) # match IP addresses
  )|( # delimiter for address formats
   ((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)?)+?) # match domains and any number of subdomains
   (\.) #dot for .com
   ([a-z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum) #TLD clause
  ) # end address clause
([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\&\%\/]*)? # querystring support, will pretty this up later
$
```

is matching:

> www.google

and shouldn't be. This is one of my "fail" test cases. I have declared the TLD portion of the URL to be mandatory when matching on alpha instead of on IP, and "google" doesn't fit into the "[a-z]{2}" clause.

Keep in mind I will fix the following issues seperately - this question is about why it matches www.google and shouldn't.

- Querystring needs to support proper formats only, currently accepts any combination of querystring characters
- Several protocols not supported, though the scope of my requirements may not include them
- uncommon TLDs with 3 characters not included
- Probably matches http://www.google..com - will check for consecutive dots
- Doesn't support decimal IP address formats

**What's wrong with my regex?**

edit: See also a previous problem with an earlier version of this regex on a different test case:
[How can I make this regex match correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622446/how-can-i-make-this-regex-match-correctly)

edit2: Fixed - The corrected regex (as asked) is:

> ^((https?|ftp)\:(\/\/)|(file\:\/{2,3}))?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
> (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)?)+?)(\.)([a-z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum))([\/][\/a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)*?([\/]?[\?][a-zA-Z0-9\=\&\%\/]*)?$

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622446/how-can-i-make-this-regex-match-correctly

Comment: I wouldn't say the *question* is an exact duplicate, but surely the *answer* should be.

Comment: No, that one had a different regex, if I edit it nobody will go back to it.

Comment: ... and also, the match is different from the one i asked about on that one.

Comment: Okay, well if not "exact duplicate" then "highly related" and a useful link for answerers. In the future, if you're referring to a previous question please say so, so that answerers can find out what you've learned previously.

Comment: What is your intention? If it's to validate urls, then www.google is a valid (though nonexistent) url.

Comment: This particular regex is to validate urls within the scope of internet addresses (may adjust ip section later). Will develop another for local and another for any scope. In this case I'm not looking for a computer called www on a local domain called google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"google" might not fit in `[a-z]{2}`, but it does fit in `[a-z]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\&\%\/]*)?` - you forgot to require a `/` after the TLD if the URL extends beyond the domain. So it's interpreting it with "www.go" as the domain and then "ogle" following it, with no slash in between. You can fix it by adding a `[?/]` to the front of that last group to require one of those two symbols between the TLD and any further portion of the URL.

Comment: so http://www.example.com?a=b&c=d  isn't a valid url because there's no / before the ??

Comment: @tslib: it is as in fact not a valid url.

Comment: @Residuum: Then why does C#'s Request.Querystring[] pick it up? :)

Comment: @tsilb: Your example is in fact a valid URL. There was a question regarding that exact case here on SO a few days ago, but since it's essentially impossible to search for "com?" I'm afraid I can't find a link to it.

Comment: tsilb: there's a reason why I recommended adding `[?/]` and not just `/` - because either would be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Your TLD clause matches "go" in google and the querystring support part matches "ogle" afterwards. Try changing the querystring part to this:

```
([?/][a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\&\%\/]*)?
```

Comment: Bah, that's right, when I removed the specifically-formatted querystring stuff (Failures, figured I'd fix it after the rest of it works), I forgot it no longer delimits on the question mark!

Answer (score 2):

> google" doesn't fit into the "[a-z]{2}" clause.

But  "go" does and then "ogle" matches "([a-zA-Z0-9\?\=\&\%/]*)?"